# How can I create a Jquery XHR for images from an api and change images with an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, onclick, jqxhr

Good afternoon everyone.

I'm attempting to display a set of images in a div, and use JQuery to fetch images from an API that changes the set of images when one of the header options are clicked. Any ideas?

Trying to get a set of four 'set' images from an api, then, display a different set when one of the options is clicked. The preferred method would be Jquery, but it seems like I'm not finding a lot of documentation on how to proceed. I apologize if this question is below you, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="first-div">
  <div id="div-holder">
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="image-links">
```

The options below should all be set with an initial set of images from a remote api and when each option is clicked, a new set of images is displayed.

```
<div class="option"><a href=""></a>Articles</div>
                        
<div class="option"><a href=""></a>Videos</div>
                        
<div class="option"><a href=""></a>Facts & Hacks</div>
                        
<div class="option"><a href=""></a>Infographics</div>
                        
<div class="option"><a href=""></a>Link Meanings</div>
                    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first-div{
  background-color: #fafafb;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  border-bottom: .05rem solid #ddd;
}

.div-holder {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 64rem;
}

.image-links {
  border-bottom: .05rem solid #ddd;
  max-width: 43rem;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would first advise that you take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour Next you will want to present a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Twisty. I'll definitely do that. What did you notice specifically about the question that needs revision, or was it complete trash? Lol. Thanks again

Comment: The edits are highly useful. I'll make use of them. However, Stack wouldn't even let me ask the question until it was formatted *exactly* the way you found it Twisty. Between the three of us, one of us is missing something. I'm all ears.